# RTSP: RTP uses the same port as RTSP

Tags: networking, gstreamer, rtsp

It really isn't a problem but I would like to hear from the community about this "strange" phenomenon or at least it seems to me.

I have written an RTSP application that streams video and audio (as RTP payload 96 and 97 respectively)

RTSP client make connection and setup and play correctly (the video could be seen over the client end). What I am bother about is that RTP (video and audio) is send out through TCP (through port 554). Yah I know its correct behaviour but I quite confuse that it uses the same port as RTSP (port 554). I have always have the idea that RTSP would have a static port number and after RTSP connection is established,  client would then negotiate the RTP/RTCP connection with server (which will results in creation of additional port (4 in my case). However, it seem that all RTP/RTSP/RTCP traffic is tunneled through the same port (or I have misinterpreted the result)

Below is the rtsp transaction captured by wireshark

```
C->S (video payload)
SETUP rtsp://192.168.22.33:554/MOVIE/stream=0 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1
User-Agent: happytimesoft rtsp client

S->C (video payload ok)
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1;ssrc=7C0EAE5B;mode="PLAY"
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Session: -8lIe87._f3qX4.h
Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 15:23:22 GMT

C->S (audio payload)
SETUP rtsp://192.168.22.33:554/MOVIE/stream=1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
Session: -8lIe87._f3qX4.h
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=2-3
User-Agent: happytimesoft rtsp client

S->C (audio payload)
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=2-3;ssrc=2E0ECCA6;mode="PLAY"
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Session: -8lIe87._f3qX4.h
Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 15:23:22 GMT

C->S
PLAY rtsp://192.168.22.33:554/MOVIE/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
Session: -8lIe87._f3qX4.h
Range: npt=0.000-
User-Agent: happytimesoft rtsp client
```

After which it plays with both of the payload into one port

[image: Package played]

Is my interpretation correct? Is there any problem of sending all communication via one port (albeit latency)? Or is there any chances that the packets might be rerouted?

Thanks

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTSP/RTP has several sending modes. Your client explicitly requests for RTSP interleaving - where RTP data gets send interleaved in the RTSP channel. That a nice fallback for firewall restricted environments. If you don't request this RTP channels should be send over their individual UDP ports.

Comment: I am of the impression that client would have made settings for client-ports (as previously in other hardware) even if it opt for RTSP/RTP/TCP mode of delivery...maybe it could be a lack of knowledge on my part.  Won't the above configuration result in a slow, laggy experience over the client end since all traffic is to be routed to the same port

Comment: Using ports from 0-65000 wont magically boost your performance by 65000x. Most performance difference may yield from the differences of transport layers of TCP and UDP. With all their pros and cons.

Comment: Just a thought... what if an RTSP request came from another client trying to access port 554 in my example? since this port 554 is being used for RTP/TCP transport... would it still be able to accept the new RTSP request

Comment: Sure, it is TCP. It is not stateless compared to UDP. A new client is a new connection. Also it does not send RTP/RTCP, it does send RTSP (just happens to wrap RTP/RTCP data in this case).

Comment: on the same port? that has traffic? ok

Comment: Ever wondered how web servers respond to thousands of clients simultaneously on port 80? ;-)

Comment: that's a good example!!

Answer (score 1):

Reason it uses TCP (your main concern) is that it uses TCP is that the default is in this trying order: `tcp+udp-mcast+udp`: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtsp/rtspsrc.html#rtspsrc:protocols

You can force UDP by setting the `rtspsrc` parameter `protocols` to `GST_RTSP_LOWER_TRANS_UDP`. Or in `gst-launch-1.0` -> `protocols=1`

Comment: Btw, you can always add `GST_DEBUG=2` in front of the gstreamer command or application to see why it is taking TCP over UDP. `E.g.: Could not receive any UDP packets for 5.0000 seconds, maybe your firewall is blocking it.`
Debug level 2 shows you error & warning traces.